# Character Encoding: Why my email receiving code cannot run in PyQt4?

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding, pyqt4

I am recently finishing a spam classification application as my final project and now I meet a problem.
The problem came from a module to receive emails. I wrote the test code in a single .py file and it worked really well. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
# coding=utf-8  
import poplib  
from email import parser  
host = 'pop.qq.com'  
username = 'xxxxx@qq.com'  
password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'  
pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL(host)  
pop_conn.user(username)  
pop_conn.pass_(password)  
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]  
# Concat message pieces:  
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]  
#print messages  
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]  
i = 0  
for message in messages:  
    i = i + 1  
    mailName = "mail"+str(i)  
    f = open(mailName + '.log', 'w');  
    print >> f, "Date: ", message["Date"]  
    print >> f, "From: ", message["From"]  
    print >> f, "To: ", message["To"]  
    print >> f, "Subject: ", message["Subject"]  
    print >> f, "Data: "  

    for part in message.walk():  
        contentType = part.get_content_type()    
        if contentType == 'text/plain' :  

            data = part.get_payload(decode=True)  
            print >> f, data  
    f.close()  
pop_conn.quit()
```

But when I tried to transplant exactly the same code to my PyQt4 application, the problem came out in this line:

```
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
```

and this is the problem:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 4:ordinal not in range(128)
```

mssg[1] is a list that contains every line of the mail. I guess this is because the text from the mail was encoded by "utf-8" or "gbk" which can't be decoded by the default "ascii". So I tried to write the code like this:

```
messages = ["\n".join([m.decode("utf-8") for m in mssg[1]]) for mssg in messages]
```

The problem became like this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 7
```

I used Python chardet module to detect the encoding of the text of the email, and it turned out to be "ascii". Now I am really confused. Why the same code can't run on my small application? What is the real problem, and how I can fix it? I will be very appreciated for your help.

Comment: Please add `!`character before your image tag to show it properly.

Comment: thx~I do not have enough reputation to post images, so I type the error message instead:-D

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by receiving the email in a .py file and using my application to import that file. This may not be useful in other situations because I actually didn't solve the character encoding problem. When I was implementing my application, I met lots of encoding problems, and it's quite annoying. For this, I guess it is caused by some irregular text from my mail(maybe some pictures) which is shown in the following picture:

[image]

This was shown when I tried to print some of my email data on the screen. However, I still don't know why this cannot run in my application, though it worked well in  a simple file. The character encoding problem is very annoying, and maybe I still have a long way to go.:-D